# How to copy a 4.2GB file to a USB flash drive

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, fat32

I have a 4.2GB file on my hard disk. I need to put it onto a USB drive to copy it to another PC. However, when I use a standard Windows 10 copying and pasting process, it tells me that the 4GB file is too large for the 16GB drive. So something is not right. How can I get that file onto the USB drive, preferably without using dodgy adware-laced freeware?

The USB drive was formatted at FAT32.

Comment: The issue is the filesystem, as explained in the proposed duplicate (and comments here), and the duplicate includes two Windows solutions (including the accepted answer), and an OS agnostic solution.

Comment: The proposed duplicate question is not actually the question I had asked. The proposed duplicate question is only useful as an answer if you already know that the issue with copying a big iso file is the format of the USB drive. If you didn't know that, then you won't know to search keywords that will lead to the proposed duplicate question. You may persist in thinking that it is an issue with copying iso files, like I did. The current question addresses that issue from this perspective. So I think the current question here is useful for others to find.

Comment: But I see the reference to an iso file has been removed from the post-edited question header. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

You should format your USB Device to NTFS to copy larg files on windows.

Other file systems can't mount on windows.

According to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) Wikipedia page, maximum file size in fat32/fat32x is 4GB.

Comment: Also exFAT is good for pendrives. Not available in Windows XP.